# Get term SLUG by term ID

Tags: custom-taxonomy, get-posts

I have a hierarchical taxonomy called 'tarefa'

I have to display all posts from a child taxonomy. I used [get_term_children function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) function to verify if the taxonomy parent has children.

If the taxonomy parent has children I will query posts by taxonomy children.

The problem is:
I have to query posts by taxonomy slug but the function get_term_children return an array of taxonomy IDS.

The question is:
How can I return a taxonomy slug by a taxonomy ID?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have bit of trouble understanding your question. Taxonomy (like `category`) slug or term (like `uncategorized`) slug?

`get_term_children()` works with terms so I will stick with that.

Try this:

```
$term = get_term( $id, $taxonomy );
$slug = $term->slug;
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with this function, it worked as expected ;) thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with less overhead?